# How to accept arbitrary string for TextField in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Which option I can use

```swift
TextField("na", value: $object.maintainer, format: .)
```

to accept any arbitrary string here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is to accept an arbitrary string. You just need `maintainer` to be of type String here and use `TextField("na", text: $object.maintainer)`. (Note `text`, not `value`. The version you're using is for things that need custom conversion, so you need to provide that custom conversion.)